# ¿Tiene nombre el signo de la cruz en un círculo que veo a veces en el DPD?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, rae, diccionarios

Cuando consulto el *Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas* a veces me encuentro ejemplos que la propia obra marca como incorrectos con un símbolo en tinta roja que es una cruz dentro de un círculo:

[image: Ejemplo del DPD]

¿Qué nombre recibe este símbolo?

Answer (score 3):

El símbolo en cuestión se llama *bolaspa*.

> **[bolaspa](https://dle.rae.es/?w=bolaspa)**
>
> De *bola* y *aspa*.
>
> 1. f. En algunos escritos que tratan sobre la lengua, signo (⊗) que precede a las formas consideradas incorrectas y a los ejemplos que ilustran usos no aceptados en la norma estándar.

Sobre el símbolo en sí, mencionar que fue creado precisamente para ser usado en el DPD, cuya primera edición es de 2005, en complemento (o sustitución) del asterisco (`*`) que [se venía usando](http://romera.blogspot.com/2007/05/bolaspa.html?_sm_au_=iVVfqVMtn4MP51j7) en obras anteriores. Su uso se extendió a otras obras, como la *Ortografía* de 2010:

[image: Bolaspa en la Ortografía]

Sin embargo, en la *Gramática* se recupera el uso del asterisco.

Su uso provoca en todo caso controversia incluso dentro de la propia ASALE, la asociación de academias de la lengua a la que pertenece la RAE y otras muchas academias hispanoamericanas. Como indica [este artículo](http://www.diariosigloxxi.com/texto-s/mostrar/339989/academicos-urgen-eliminar-bolaspa-diccionario), algunos académicos consideran ese símbolo un "símbolo de tortura medieval".

> “Ya casi no se habla de errores ortográficos o de cómo se debe hablar; no digamos que nada está mal dicho o que está prohibido, porque si todo el mundo lo dice, es saludable que empecemos a tipificarlo”, aseguró el secretario general de la Asociación de Academias de la Lengua Española (Asale), Francisco Javier Pérez. [...] “La próxima edición —que va con retraso, reconoce— hablará de lo que recomendamos, se orienta. El Panhispánico es un diccionario que decía lo que no debe usarse y que incorporó la ‘bolaspa’, un símbolo de tortura medieval y que ya el académico José Manuel Blecua —exdirector de la RAE— dijo que tenía que desaparecer”, explicó Pérez.

Comment: Lo curioso de todo esto es que, aunque el símbolo ya existía pero con poco uso, la palabra la inventó la RAE que dice de si misma: «La Academia no inventa palabras ni acepciones, y tampoco las promociona»

Comment: @blonfu me recuerda lo que ocurre con las películas que quieren participar en los Oscar: deben ser proyectadas en una sala de cine en el año anterior al concurso. Esto lleva a situaciones como proyectar prácticamente el último día del año en una sala de unos amigotes, para así cumplir el requisito. O empezar el 1 de enero, para optar el año siguiente. Es decir, _apaños legales_ para llegar al resultado que se quería. Creo relevante lo que nos llevamos tiempo preguntando [¿Tiene la RAE algún criterio a la hora de consultar textos en Internet para dar forma a su diccionario?](/q/21035/)

Comment: En este caso, me imagino a los académicos _colando_ la palabra en algún lugar para luego decir: _ey, que lo he visto usar, como notario de la lengua procedo a incluirla en el diccionario_.

Comment: @blonfu cuando has dicho que el símbolo ya existía me he puesto a buscarlo, pero lo que he encontrado es que antes se usaba el asterisco (aparece mucho, por ejemplo, en el etimológico de Corominas para indicar variantes incorrectas o etimologías dudosas). La bolaspa parece que sí que se creó para el DPD. Lo curioso es que en la _Gramática_ se volvió al asterisco. He actualizado la respuesta.

Comment: Se usaba para otras cosas por lo visto, aquí cita un ejemplo: https://addendaetcorrigenda.blogia.com/2010/040901-la-nueva-rae-un-espejismo-de-representatividad-neutralidad-ideol-gica-laborio.php

Comment: @fedorqui bueno, la palabra _bolaspa_ se incluyó en el diccionario en 2014, para entonces había creado tanta controversia que solo por eso ya se había usado en varios artículos periodísticos. Ahora mismo en Google aparecen 22500 resultados de "bolaspa".

Comment: @blonfu ah, vale, que se usaba como símbolo matemático, es cierto, pero fue la RAE quien le dio su uso como delimitador de ejemplos incorrectos y lo rebautizó.

Comment: Charlie: interesante, podría acabar como el caso de [_bizarro_](/q/17074/1674), en el que la mayoría de usos "correctos" son para explicar que no es el uso normal. Es decir, que la palabra es tan controvertida en el ámbito lingüístico que el meta-uso es mayor que el uso orgánico.